# Adding size and color with third variable to plot using plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I want to control the color and size of my markers using plotly, as the example here:

```
library(plotly)

d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]

p <- plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat, size = ~carat)
```

Now, I want to control the size using another variable and doing it over time. Then it makes a weird grouping solution.

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  Date = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2015-06-29 00:00:00"), 
                    to = as.POSIXct("2015-06-30 00:00:00"), by = "hour"), 
  a = runif(25, min = 1, max = 5000), 
  b = runif(25, min = - 20, max = 25))

# Works
plot_ly(data = mydf, x =~Date, y=~a, 
  type = "scatter", mode = "markers", name = 'a', showlegend = TRUE)

# Doesn't work
plot_ly(data = mydf, x =~Date, y=~a, 
  type = "scatter", mode = "markers", name = 'a', showlegend = TRUE, color = ~b, size =~b)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's forgetting the lims of the x-axis, because if you zoom you can see the dots correctly so, maybe a solution could be this:

```
plot_ly(data = mydf, x =~Date, y=~a, 
        type = "scatter", mode = "markers", name = 'a', showlegend = TRUE, color = ~b, size =~b) %>%
layout(xaxis = list(range = c(min(mydf$Date), max(mydf$Date))))
```

[image]

Or subtract to the min and add to the max an arbitrary quantity to not have the least and the first x-axis points on the edges, like:

```
plot_ly(data = mydf, x =~Date, y=~a, 
        type = "scatter", mode = "markers", name = 'a', showlegend = TRUE, color = ~b, size =~b) %>%
layout(xaxis = list(range = c(min(mydf$Date)-5000, max(mydf$Date)+5000)))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks - hadn't spotted that little hidden feature :)

Comment: You are welcome! Why it's changing the zoom it's still a mistery to me, however I'm glad that my quick and dirty solution helps.